# Error during any installation - grub-efi error

Tags: grub2, uefi

I am getting below error while installing software on Ubuntu. This comes during any installation.

> Setting up grub-efi-amd64 (2.02-2ubuntu8.20) ... od:
> /sys/firmware/efi/efivars/SecureBoot-8be4df61-93ca-11d2-aa0d-00e098032b8c:
> Operation not permitted /usr/share/grub/grub-check-signatures: 22: [:
> Illegal number:  dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64
> (--configure):  installed grub-efi-amd64 package post-installation
> script subprocess returned error exit status 255 dpkg: dependency
> problems prevent configuration of grub-efi-amd64-signed:
> grub-efi-amd64-signed depends on grub-efi-amd64 | grub-pc; however:
> Package grub-efi-amd64 is not configured yet.   Package grub-pc is not
> installed.
>
> dpkg: error processing package grub-efi-amd64-signed (--configure):
> dependency problems - leaving unconfigured

**Ubuntu Version**
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

Can anyone please help to fix this error.

Thanks a lot.

Regards - Roy

Comment: What brand/model system? What video card/chip? If very new system, better to install 20.04 or 20.10. Some may install easier with UEFI Secure Boot off. Windows fast start up must be off. Shows live installer with screen shots. Both BIOS purple accessibility screen & UEFI black grub menu screen 20.10 uses grub for both
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi